# Can slicers be used a stored procedure parameter in power bi to filter underlying data

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

Can we pass the slicer values as stored procedure paramter when connecting to a sql for developing a PowerBI report  so that once its deployed in powerbi service the end user can use slicer to filter the report

I tried to use a stored procedure  which uses a date paramter ,but using slicer i am unable pass as a paramter to stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

No.  You cannot directly use stored procedures in DirectQuery models.  If you use native sql in DirectQuery, it must be "composable", ie Power BI will run

```
select * from (<your query here>) b
where someslicer=somevalue...
```

So you can use multi-statement table-valued functions, and you can manipulate the native query using [Dynamic M Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-dynamic-m-query-parameters), and there's a workaround where you use OPENQUERY against a loopback linked server to run a stored procedure. [How to use SQL Server stored procedures in Microsoft PowerBI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37589448/how-to-use-sql-server-stored-procedures-in-microsoft-powerbi)